# How to refresh the browser in a coded ui test

Tags: coded-ui-tests

My application is up and running in IE 9 but sometimes not everything loads properly on the page and it causes my coded ui test to fail.  So I want to add code to my coded ui test to refresh (F5) the browser when this happens.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

When you launch the web browser it returns an instance of the `BrowserWindow` object. That `BrowserWindow` object contains a `Rrefresh` method you can call:

```
BrowserWindow currentBrowser = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("https://www.google.com/"));
currentBrowser.Refresh();
```

You can also call use the `Locate` method to get an instance of the `BrowserWindow` you are using if you need to do the refresh in a different place:

```
BrowserWindow currentBrowser = BrowserWindow.Locate("title of your browser window");
currentBrowser.Refresh();
```